# My Template is not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

MainController.js

```
app.controller("mainController", function($scope, $http){
$scope.movies = [];
$scope.searchFilter = '';
$scope.init = function() {

};

$scope.getMovies = function(){
    var movieName = $('#MovieName').val();
    var movies = getMovies(movieName); // Gets json
    $scope.parseMovies(movies);    
};

$scope.parseMovies = function(movies){
    $scope.movies = [];
    $.each(movies, function( index, value ) {
        $scope.movies.push($scope.createMovie(value));
    });
};

$scope.createMovie = function(json){
    Movie=new Object();
    Movie.id=json.id;
    Movie.title=json.title;
    Movie.year=json.year;
    Movie.runtime=json.runtime;
    return Movie;
};

});
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('MoviesApp',[]);
```

html

```
<body ng-controller="MovieListCtrl">    
    <div class="container main-frame" ng-app="MoviesApp" ng-controller="mainController">
        <input type="text" id="MovieName" />
        <input type="button" data-ng-click="getMovies()" />        
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="movie in movies">
                {{movie.title}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>    
</body>
```

When I click the button and `getMovies()` is called the data is retrieved ok but the template does not get filled. Only when I click the button again does it get filled.

The thing is when it is clicked the second time, the template gets filled before the new json is retrieved (I put a breakpoint in the script).

I'm stuck

Comment: First of all - all that logic should not be in your controller. All the methods with `Movie` in their name should be in a service, or in plain JS objects unrelated to Angular. Second of all, getMovies is recursive and never makes any HTTP requests - what does it even do? Third of all, when you take code and run it using things like jQuery outside the Angular cycle, you need to call `$scope.$apply` to connect it back in, but if you write your code correctly you shouldn't have to do it anyway.

Comment: He used ng-click so he's inside the angular cycle, why does he need $scope.$apply ?

Comment: @EranH. because of the code _not_ being shown here. I see `$.each` which makes me assume there is a `$.ajax` instead of using `$http` somewhere, the above code is not full. This also looks like a textbook  example of this given what he is seeing. "When I click the button and getMovies() is called the data is retrieved ok but the template does not get filled. Only when I click the button again does it get filled." sounds exactly like digest cycle misuse.

Comment: You're right, it's probably an ajax call inside getMovies. I made a fiddle to demonstrate that with a simple getMovies function it will work: http://jsfiddle.net/7bdfp/